# Godot/GdScript How to instantiate a class from a static function?

Tags: static, godot, gdscript

I have 2 scripts:

A.gd

```
class_name A    

var v = 0    

func _init(v_):
    v = v_
```

B.gd

```
class_name B

var A = preload("res://A.gd")

static func Add(a1:A, a2:A):
    return A.new(a1.v + a2.v)
```

I don't understand why I have this error while I'm typing:

> res://B.gd:6 - Parse Error: Can't access member variable ("A") from a static function.

Apparently, I can't instantiate `A` from a static function. If I remove `static`, there are no more errors. What am I doing wrong? How can I instantiate `A` from a static function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no static variables in Godot. Thus that `var A` is not a static variable. And thus it is not available from a static function.

On the other hand, if you gave a name to your class with `class_name` - which you did - then that class name exist everywhere. Remove `var A`.

Comment: Nice. I kind of fixed it by using `const A` but your answer seems much better. I will try it ASAP.